# Vector Derivative With Rotor

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

i would like to know the demonstration of the derivative of the following function

$$ J = \frac{1}{|| \boldsymbol{r} \times \boldsymbol{v} ||^{2}}$$

Suppose a planar surface (x-y plane) with $\boldsymbol{r}$ the position vector and $\boldsymbol{v}$ a two components velocity vector in the plane. $\boldsymbol{n}$ represents the normal vector with respect to the surface.

$$ \frac{\partial J}{\partial \boldsymbol{v}} = -2 \frac{\boldsymbol{n} \times \boldsymbol{r} }{|| \boldsymbol{r} \times \boldsymbol{v} ||^{3}}$$

Then i would like to calculate the derivative of a similar function

$$ J = \frac{1}{|| \boldsymbol{\nabla} \times \boldsymbol{v} ||^{2}}$$

$$ \frac{\partial J}{\partial \boldsymbol{v}} = ??$$

Many thanks for your help!

Best regards,
Yella

Comment: Hi @MarkViola, first thank you for your reply. I really don't know. I was reading a paper and the author didn't report any passage. The only informations are those i reported in the starting post. I'm sorry i cannot add other informations and be more precise.

Comment: Typically, the derivative of a scalar $f$ with respect to a vector $\vec v$ is a vector with $i$'th component $\frac{\partial f}{\partial v_i}$, which is the $i$'th component of the gradient, $\nabla_v f \cdot \hat v_i$.

Comment: Ok, i'll work tomorrow about it and post the solution in case of success. Thanks for your suggestion